# Auto Running program c++

Tags: c++, windows, telegram, startup

I am trying to make a c++ program that boots whenever the computer does.

when i click on the executable, what is does, is copying itself in the startup folder

```
int CopyPasteFile(bool overWrite=true)
{
        wchar_t this_exe_path[MAX_PATH];
        if (!GetModuleFileName(NULL, this_exe_path, MAX_PATH)) // this exe path basically
            return -1;

        if (!SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_STARTUP, NULL, 0, startup_path))) path to get to, the windows startup folder
            return -2;

        auto from = experimental::filesystem::path(this_exe_path);
        thisFilename = from;

        to = experimental::filesystem::path(startup_path) / "program.exe";

        if (!CopyFile(from.c_str(), to.c_str(), overWrite))
        {
            return -3; //copies itself there
        }


        return 0;   

}
```

here we are, the code can get my program to copy itself in that folder.

what happens next though, is that whenever the computer boots up, the program does, but cannot create text files, which i need here

```
int CheckForMessages()
    {

        SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = { 0 };

        info.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
        info.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
        info.hwnd = NULL;
        info.lpVerb = NULL;
        info.lpFile = L"cmd.exe ";
        info.lpParameters = LR"( /c "FOR /F "tokens=*" %g IN ('curl --get https://api.telegram.org/botXXX:YYY/getupdates') do (SET VAR=%g%) & echo %g>File.txt" )";
        info.lpDirectory = NULL;
        info.nShow = SW_HIDE;
        info.hInstApp = NULL;
        ShellExecuteEx(&info); //creates File.txt and stores telegram's response there 

        Sleep(2000);


        fstream f("File.txt", fstream::in);
        string s;                               //reads it and gets it into the string s
        getline(f, s, '\0');

        string ToFind[2] = { R"("text":"command1")", R"("text":"command2")" };
        string MyChatID= "00000000";

        if ( (s.find(ToFind[0]) != string::npos) && (s.find(MyChatID) != string::npos) )//command1
        {
            sendMessage("command1+executed");
            f.close();
            remove("File.txt");
            return -1;
        }
```

what that does, is basically telling me when the computer booted up, and let me perform actions using telegram.

it stores the request in a File.txt, then reads it, then deletes it. 
what happens though, is that when i boot up my pc, i get the messages from the bot, but the program cannot create the txt file, for some reason.

if i go and execute the program personally though, by clicking on the exe, everything works perfectly fine

What i get from my bot basically is the output of that code right here, which is at the top of the main function

```
telegram tg;
    tg.sendMessage("computer+booted+up");
```

which is a message from the bot that says "computer booted up"

I have tried a lot of different things, even got the program to execute itself twice, but nothing worked at all without my input!

what can i do? thank you all, i am a 14yo who is trying to get into developing, but it's all pretty hard for me, also the language, since i'm not a native english speaker... but anyways, thank you for your help

EDIT: i tried to get the error, and it returns 0, as if it is all normal.

'''

```
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = { 0 };
    info.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
    info.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    info.hwnd = NULL;
    info.lpVerb = NULL;
    info.lpFile = L"cmd.exe ";
    info.lpParameters = LR"( /c "FOR /F "tokens=*" %g IN ('curl --get https://api.telegram.org/botXXX:YYY/getupdates') do (SET VAR=%g%) & echo %g>File.txt" )";
    info.lpDirectory = NULL;
    info.nShow = SW_HIDE;
    info.hInstApp = NULL;
    ShellExecuteEx(&info);
    int a = GetLastError();

    MessageBox(0, to_wstring(a).c_str(), 0, 0);
```

'''

Comment: @ChrisMM i cant figure out how to do it, how to store the error code, since it simply is being executed, but does less than half of what it should do... i tried whatever i could! But just dont get it! Could it be some kind of Windows limitation? Because, i repeat, when I manually execute it, it works!

Comment: Is it this line that fails? `fstream f("File.txt", fstream::in);`? If `File.txt` does not exist, it will fail to open. I might be misunderstanding the problem though.

Comment: i dont think so, because it works everytime i manually open it!

Comment: that makes no sense to me, i have been trying for three days straight!

Comment: Check the result of `ShellExecuteEx`, if it is `FALSE`, call `GetLastError()` and see what it says. Sorry, I missed the part where the file was created, which seems to be what the ShellExecute call is doing.

Comment: done, error code 0, as if it is all normal, but it's not...

Comment: that was the code i used to get the error

Comment: SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = { 0 };

  info.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
  info.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  info.hwnd = NULL;
  info.lpVerb = NULL;
  info.lpFile = L"cmd.exe ";
  info.lpParameters = LR"( /c "FOR /F "tokens=*" %g IN ('curl --get https://api.telegram.org/botXXX:YYY/getupdates') do (SET VAR=%g%) & echo %g>File.txt" )";
  info.lpDirectory = NULL;
  info.nShow = SW_HIDE;
  info.hInstApp = NULL;
  ShellExecuteEx(&info);
  int a = GetLastError();
  MessageBox(0, to_wstring(a).c_str(), 0, 0);

Comment: My best assumption would be that that call is failing. If `ShellExecuteEx` is not failing itself, then I would assume the command it runs is failing, but I do not know why it would fail in this case, but not when run on its own. Sorry, that's all I got.

Comment: dont worry, and thanks a lot anyways... i'll keep trying!

Comment: Sidenote: A program in the in the Windows start-up folder only starts when the user logs in. The computer may have booted long before that. Depending on your goals you may need to look into a Windows service.

Comment: It is fine for me that it starts up when the user logs in, the problem is that it doesnt work fine, and i have no idea why. Windows services may be useful later on anyway, thanks!

Comment: @NicolaVassallo, one more idea. Try calling the command more directly, without `ShellExecute` and grab the output in c++ code and print it out yourself. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3578548/10686048) on how to do that. On Windows, it's `_popen` instead of `popen` though. [More info on command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen?view=vs-2019)

Comment: i'll make sure to try that as well. thanks a lot, i''l let you know (im probably going to bed now, im here trying to fix that since 6PM), thank you for everything!

Comment: run *cmd.exe*absolute senseless here. direct run *curl.exe* or what you want. and not with `ShellExecuteEx` but with `CreateProcessW`

Comment: I'll try that as well, thanks!

Comment: @ChrisMM i found something here                                                        
```std::string exec(const char* cmd) {
 std::array<char, 128> buffer;
 std::string result;
 std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&_pclose)> pipe(_popen(cmd, "r"), _pclose);
 if (!pipe) {
  throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
 }
 while (fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) != nullptr) {
  result += buffer.data();
 }
 return result;
}```
//what happens though, is that a window appears, and i cant close it, even though my process is in win32!